# Plugin and theme script load order

Tags: plugins, wp-register-script

I'm building a plugin that adds scripts to the page using `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script`. However, when the page loads, it's loading the plugin scripts before the theme's scripts. This is causing some errors because the theme is loading jQuery, which needs to be loaded first. Is there a way of making the plugin script load last, so that the theme script is loading first in the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For scritps and using the wp_register_script() function, you can define the dependeny of jQuery in the $deps argument, which is documented as:

> $deps: Array of the handles of all the registered scripts that this script
>   depends on, that is, the scripts that must be loaded before this
>   script. These scripts will automatically be enqueued when this script
>   is enqueued with wp_enqueue_script(). Set false if there are no
>   dependencies. Default: array()
>   http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

Example:

```
wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-jquery-custom.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
```